# Помогите разобраться с запуском python.exe из cmd

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmd

Столкнулся с проблемой, про которую можно найти информацию в интернете, но хочется совета именно отсюда. 
У меня установлен Visual Studio 2017 и пакеты Anaconda v2, v3; а также python 3.6, нужно чтобы компилятор запускался из cmd.exe и при этом выполнял файлы .py

Я правильно понимаю, что если пишу `..>python 'имя программы'.py`, то программа запускается из той же папки, где и лежит python.exe? (даже ответ на этот вопрос будет достаточен)

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Никита Пермяков>python
"python" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Извините за банальный вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Разобрался сам, действительно, ничего сложного.

```
Панель управления - система - дополнительные параметры системы - 
переменные среды - системные переменные - и добавить путь к python.exe
```